# redux selector is not filtering nested array accordingly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to filter posts where Likes userId is equal to params.userId, as of now im getting an empty array. Ideally it should get all posts, that the params.userId has liked.

**selector**

```
export const getUserPosts = (params) => {
    return createSelector(
        postSelector,
        (state) => {
            const findIndex = state.posts.findIndex((x) => x.userId == params.userId);
            console.log(findIndex)
            // const likedPosts = state.posts.reduce((acc, cv) => {
            //     const newPosts = {
            //         Likes: cv.Likes.filter((item) => item.userId == params.userId)
            //     }
            //     const newerPosts = newPosts.Likes.length !== 0 ? newPosts.Likes : []
            //     console.log(newerPosts)

            //     return { acc, newerPosts }
            // }, [])
            // console.log(likedPosts)
            return state.posts.filter((item) => item.Likes.userId == params.userId)
        }
    )
}
```

Array shape

```
{
  "id": 7,
  "title": "another testf",
  "postContent": "fsfsfsfsfssfsf",
  "likedByMe": false,
  "likeCounts": 1,
  "userId": 81,
  "createdAt": "2020-01-22T02:59:17.763Z",
  "updatedAt": "2020-01-23T02:49:40.801Z",
  "author": {
    "username": "barnowl2",
    "gravatar": "https://i.pravatar.cc/150?img=11",
    "bio": null
  },
  "Likes": [
    {
      "id": 11,
      "userId": 81,
      "resourceId": 7,
      "createdAt": "2020-01-23T02:32:52.761Z",
      "updatedAt": "2020-01-23T02:32:52.761Z"
    }
  ],
  "Comments": []
}
```

Comment: Is the above "Array shape" a sample of your `posts` object?

Comment: Yes justin it is.

Comment: It looks like you are dealing with multi-level arrays. The `Likes` property is an array, so you would need to filter on that for the matching id. `item.Likes.userId` in your last line will not work, because you need the index number for the `Likes` array to get the `userId` value.

Comment: could you possibly provide a code solution ? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a multi-level array of Posts and their Likes. If you need to find all the Posts with Likes that match a particular userId, I think it would be like this:

```
state.posts.filter(post => {
  return post.Likes.find(like => like.userId === params.userId)
})
```

`.find()` will run through the Likes and return the object or null, which will inform `.filter()` whether or not to include the Post